# docker-compose: How to pass secret to environment variable in logstash?

Tags: docker-compose, environment-variables, logstash, elastic-stack

I'm running elk stack on docker swarm, and I've a problem with env variables.
Here is a variable "ELASTIC_PASSWORD_FILE" inside of a container. This variable is created by "ENV ELASTIC_PASSWORD_FILE elastic" in Dockerfile.

```
bash-4.2$ export
declare -x ELASTIC_CONTAINER="true"
declare -x ELASTIC_PASSWORD_FILE="/run/secrets/elastic_password.txt"
```

I'm trying to change it's value by environment variable in docker-compose file by doing something like below:

```yaml
secrets: 
  - source: elasticsearch_password
    target: /run/secrets/elasticsearch_password.txt
    mode: 0600
    uid: "1000"
    gid: "1000"
environment:
  - LS_JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx256m -Xms256m
  - ELASTIC_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/elastic_password.txt
```

How to inject content of a file from /run/secrets/elastic_password.txt to the environment variable?

I'm running elk 7.7.0

Answer (score -3):

Check [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#version-33) official documentation to use configs and read from your text file.

Comment: I've checked it out. Maybe I'm missing something, but in my understanding, official image of logstash shoud get the contents of a file, when the environment variable name is ending with "FILE". However, it's not working like that.

Comment: Hi @ankitmhhatre. When posting a link to an external resource you should also quote the most relevant section of the referenced material. Links often break. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.